# Android name resolution in internal server doesn't work (device and emulator)

Tags: android, nslookup

i try to connect (HttpClient) to an internal server in my app via wi-fi. But every time i got an UnknownHostException if I use the domain name of the server (http://domainname/..). If i use the Ip instead, it works well. 
This happens not only on the emulator but also on a real device (htc desire).

Did anyone got the same problem?
Solutions i found in web only refer the problem to emulator.
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg16951.html

Thanks for your support

Comment: Update: It is possible to connect to the internal server with the full qualified server name such as http://servername.dnsSuffix  .. I guess android doesn't get the dns suffix search list and only try to connect with http://servername.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Android does not implement the DHCP option "DNS search list". See [bug #8030](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8030).

Comment: I think that this must be the solution as I didn't find any other possibile reason for that problem. Thanks!